# I'm having trouble uploading images in firebase using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

this is my hook

```
useEffect(() => {
        //references
        const storageRef = projectStorage.ref(file.name);

        storageRef.put(file).on('state-changed', (snap) => {
            let percentage = (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes)*100;
            setProgress(percentage)
        }, async () => {
            const url = await storageRef.getDownloadURl();
            setUrl(url);
        })
# [file]);
```

this is the error i'm getting. I don't understand the problem. What should I do?

```
Uncaught TypeError: _firebase_config__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.projectStorage.ref is not a function
```

It gives me an error when uploading the photo

Comment: Hi @Daniel, could you please include how you import your `firebase-storage` module. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have [Firebase Modular SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) (`v9.0.0`) installed where `ref()` is a top level function. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
const storageRef = ref(projectStorage, file.name);

uploadBytes(storageRef, file).then(async (snapshot) => {
  console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');

  const url = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
  console.log("URL", url)
});
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/create-reference) to learn more about the new syntax.